# Timeline Schedule Pages events - Servicenow

Tags: servicenow

I'm starting to work using servicenow, and I've an issue with TimeLines and the doubleClick events.

I configured the schedule page and ScriptInclude (code as pseudo-code):

**Schedule Page**

```
glideTimeline.setReadOnly(true); glideTimeline.showLeftPane(true);
glideTimeline.registerEvent("getItems", "MyTimelineScriptInclude");


function doubleClickCustomFunction(evt) {
   try {
      alert('double click: ' + "evt: " + evt + ', target: ' + target );
      action.setRedirectURL( 'my_application.do?sys_id=' + target );
   catch (exception) {
      gs.log(exception);
   }
},
```

**MyTimelineScriptInclude**

```
var MyTimelineScriptInclude = Class.create();
MyTimelineScriptInclude.prototype = Object.extendsObject(AbstractTimelineSchedulePage, {


   _getTickets: function(){
      tickets = foo();
      return tickets;
   }

   getItems: function() {
      try {

         var ticket_list = this._getTickets();

         for (var ticket in ticket_list) {
            this._representTicket(ticket_list[ticket].sys_id);
         }


      } catch(exception) {
         this._debugLog(exception, "getItemsException");
      }
   },


   _representTicket: function(sys_id) {

      // ticket Object;
      ticket_object = getTicket(sys_id);
      var timelineItem = new TimelineItem('my_application' , ticket_object.sys_id);
      _representSpans( timelineItem , ticket_object );
      this.add(timelineItem);


   },

   _representSpans: function( timelineItem , ticket_object ) {

         var timelineItemSpan1 = timelineItem.createTimelineSpan(''); // I'm not including any value into the span creator.
         timelineItemSpan1.setTimeSpan( ticket_object.startDateTime1.getNumericValue() , ticket_object.endDateTime1.getNumericValue() );
         timelineItemSpan1.setSpanText(ticket_object.spanText);
         timelineItemSpan1.setSpanColor(ticket_object.spanColor);
         timelineItemSpan1.setTooltip(ticket_object.spanTooltip);


         var timelineItemSpan2 = timelineItem.createTimelineSpan(''); // I'm not including any value into the span creator.
         timelineItemSpan2.setTimeSpan( ticket_object.startDateTime2.getNumericValue() , ticket_object.endDateTime2.getNumericValue() );
         timelineItemSpan2.setSpanText(ticket_object.spanText);
         timelineItemSpan2.setSpanColor(ticket_object.spanColor);
         timelineItemSpan2.setTooltip(ticket_object.spanTooltip);

         var timelineItemSpan3 = timelineItem.createTimelineSpan(''); // I'm not including any value into the span creator.
         timelineItemSpan3.setTimeSpan( ticket_object.startDateTime2.getNumericValue() , ticket_object.endDateTime2.getNumericValue() );
         timelineItemSpan3.setSpanText(ticket_object.spanText);
         timelineItemSpan3.setSpanColor(ticket_object.spanColor);
         timelineItemSpan3.setTooltip(ticket_object.spanTooltip);
   },
});
```

The problem is when I double click on a timeline row, it triggers the doubleClickCustomFunction, but, it isn't able to get any evt data, so, It doesn't performs the redirection.

Best regards

Comment: How are you registering the "doubleClickCustomFunction" as an event handler (and where)?

Answer (score 1):

Schedule Pages in ServiceNow use client-side script, so if the doubleClickCustomFunction is part of the schedule page client script, the server-side calls (action.setRedirect and gs.log) will fail.

The default double click function contains the following parameters: event, this, strRecordSysID, strUserSysID
I haven't used a custom doubleclick override, so I'm not sure if these parameters are automatically available. However, this is the case for other custom overrides written within the script include, such as elementMoveX

Other than that, you might try calling window.event within the function if it is a part of the client script